# Calling WCF (on Azure) from Swift 2.0 fails with status code 400

Tags: ios, wcf, azure, swift2, braintree

Trying to invoke a WCF service hosted on Azure, fails with HTTP error 400. The Web service in essence is acting as my Braintree (mobile payments) **server** side of things.

Here's the relevant code:

```
let soapEnvelope = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Header><Action s:mustUnderstand=\"1\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none\">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GenerateToken</Action></s:Header><s:Body><GenerateToken xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" /></s:Body></s:Envelope>"

let soapEnvelopeLength = String(soapEnvelope.characters.count)

let clientTokenURL = NSURL(string: "http://xxx.xxx.net/Service1.svc")
let clientTokenRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: clientTokenURL!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

clientTokenRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
clientTokenRequest.HTTPBody = soapEnvelope.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

clientTokenRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
clientTokenRequest.addValue(soapEnvelopeLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
clientTokenRequest.addValue("http://tempuri.org/IService1/GenerateToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "soapAction")

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(clientTokenRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    print(response)
    let clientToken = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let brainTree = Braintree(clientToken: clientToken!)

    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        }
    })
task.resume()
```

Failure occurs on:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(clientTokenRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
```

My soapEnvelope is pretty much a copy/paste of the auto-generated XML from WCF Test Client tool.

I also tried with the following soapEnvelope, but still getting a 400. As a result clientToken remains nil and BTree is never initialised:

```
let soapEnvelope = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"><s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><GenerateToken xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" /></s:Body></s:Envelope>"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Polis

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question after monitoring traffic with Fiddler, I had to change SOAP envelope to:

```
let soapEnvelope = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><GenerateToken xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\" /></s:Body></s:Envelope>"
```

This worked.